# Database won't delete

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

A database appeared in Sql Server that I can't seem to get rid of.  It is empty, and I am not sure how it got there, but it may be because I have been playing around with Sql Server Projects in VS, including publishing them to Sql Server.

When I try to delete, it just hangs in SSMS, until I force the window to close by closing SSMS.

Have tried taking it offline, and then backonline again, but still refuses to delete.

Also tried restarting Sql Server but still won't delete.

It started out in Single User mode, so I switched it to multi-user mode, but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Greg

Comment: What is the error message you get when trying to delete?

Comment: There is no error, the dialog just stays open saying "executing" until I get tired of looking at it (5 min)

Comment: It may be some/one of your applications using it (i.e. unclosed connections). Wait and see what the message is. If it is due to an unclosed connection you might get the option to `force to delete` or something.

Comment: It will go offline, and then back online again.  I tried this, and then deleting it, but again, no luck.

Comment: Can you query any data from that database? or is it corrupted? Try to restore a back up of another database over it and then try to delete. Trial and error approach...

Comment: There is no data in it, never had.  But I did try adding a table, and putting data in it, and it worked just fine.  But again, it won't delete, even with the close connection option.

Comment: Try to restore a backup of another database on to it and then delete.